# Sublime Text 2 autocomplete classname and method [PHP]

Tags: php, plugins, sublimetext2

I change Netbean IDE to sublime Text 2.Not so long ago, 
My project is have filesystem below :

- Public_html

  - apis

    - test.api.php
  - include

    - myclass.inc.php
  - js
  - css
  - ...

in include/myclass.inc.php (example)

```
class Myclass {

      public function testmethod(){
            echo "HELLO";
      }
}
```

in apis/test.api.php. I want to use class form include folder.
example:

```
$testclass = new Myclass();
$testclass->testmethod();
```

When I type **$testclass = new** . Sublime isn't list name of class  in my project.If I create many class. I don't know name of class.

Same to, When I type **$testclass->**. Sublime isn't list name of method in class.If in class is many method.I need to find method in class.

I want it to show the name of class when I type '**new**'. and I want it to show the name of method in class when I type '**->**'.After that I selected the name and It's auto complete. Same as Netbean.

Would you recommend me?

Comment: I would you use an IDE like netbeans and not a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't need to go with IDE you can use package. there are so much packages available for sublime you can go and search [here](https://packagecontrol.io/)

Press ctrl+shift+p (Windows, Linux) or cmd+shift+p (OS X) to open the Command Pallete. Start typing 'install' to select 'Package Control: Install Package', then search for AllAutocomplete and select it.

code:- [here](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete)

Comment: Thank you. It 's most useful